# custom XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

```
var open = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;

XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(method, uri, async, user, pass) {
    this.addEventListener("readystatechange", function(event) {  
    if(this.readyState == 4){
       var self = this;
       var response = {
         method: method,
         uri: uri,
         responseText: self.responseText
      };
      console.log(response);  
    } else {
        console.log(this.readyState);
    }
    }, false);
  open.call(this, method, uri, async, user, pass);
};
```

I am trying to listen for XHR before they are being sent. Something similar to jQuery's [beforeSend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) in the `$.ajax` method.

My goal is to listen for all XHR's before they are being sent. I suppose the closest thing would be to check above if `this.readyState === 1`?

Would the code above cause any ajax libraries like jQuery to malfunction because I use prototype on `XMLHttpRequest`?

Comment: "*listen for all XHR's before they are being sent*" - what do you want to listen for then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I am trying to listen for XHR before they are being sent.

Then try to spoof the `send()` method, not the `open()` one.

> Would the code above cause any ajax libraries like jQuery to malfunction because I use prototype on XMLHttpRequest?

No, not really. Only,

- it won't work where those libs choose not to use `XMLHttpRequest` (particularly IE)
- …and even fail if the browser does not support the `XMLHttpRequest` object (or does not support accessing or modifying its prototype)
- libs might be able to work around your spoof by dereferencing the functions before you can (though I don't know any common lib that does)
- Your code calls the native method with a fixed number of arguments, not sure if that affects anything, and it does not re-return the result (even if we know it's `undefined`). To be 100% sure, use `return open.apply(this, arguments);`.

Comment: Thank you. Regarding your IE comment: Doesn't IE <= 7 support the `XMLHttpRequest` object. Below is ActiveX if I recall correctly?

Comment: Yep. Have a look at [the old jQuery source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/d41b983259042d3a07ae785c09f71c68d9ce7c3f/src/ajax/xhr.js#L12) :-)

Comment: Hehe :) What do you think of my updated solution? A closure would keep the original object intact, right? As long as I don't attach it to `window`

Comment: What do you mean by "intact"? Apart from not leaking the `open`/`send` variable, there's no functional difference.

Comment: In my last example I don't attach `XMLHttpRequest` back to `window`. Isn't that a safer route than the first example?

Comment: There's no difference in your use of `XMLHttpRequest` between the two snippets. You use it as a global variable, and access its `prototype` property, nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert this script as a DOM element, but the following code is what works for me for 90% of all network requests:

**response_interceptor.js**

```
(function () {
  console.log(' REQUEST INTERCEPTOR INJECTED');
  let CE_id = 'Your Chrome Extension ID';
  let WithNetworkPayload;
  let gotResponse = false;
  let job_network_payload = [];
  let job_network_urls = [];
    var XHR = XMLHttpRequest.prototype;
      var send = XHR.send;
      var open = XHR.open;
      XHR.open = function (method, url) {
        this.url = url; // the request url
        request_list.push({
          request: this,
          args: arguments,
        });
        job_network_urls.push(url);
        return open.apply(this, arguments);
      };
      //Get response from chosen request
      XHR.send = function () {
        this.addEventListener('load', function () {
          console.log('Got Response ');
          console.log(this);
          try {
            this.response
              .text()
              .then((res) => {
                job_network_payload.push({ endpoint: this.url, payload: res });
                console.log(res);
              })
              .catch((err) => {
                job_network_payload.push({ endpoint: this.url, payload: err });
                console.log('❌ Error on getting response.Text()');
                console.log(err);
              });
          } catch (err) {
            console.log('❌ Error on getting response.Text()');
            console.log(err);
            job_network_payload.push({
              endpoint: this.url,
              payload: this.response,
            });
          }
          //sendResponsetoBackground(this.response);
        });
        return;
      };
    })();
```

Use a common contentScript.js to add response_interceptor.js as a DOM element:

**contentScript.js**

```
function inject_response_interceptor() {
  function interceptData() {
    var xhrOverrideScript = document.createElement('script');
    xhrOverrideScript.type = 'text/javascript';
    xhrOverrideScript.src = chrome.runtime.getURL(
      './injected_scripts/response_interceptor.js'
    );
    document.head.prepend(xhrOverrideScript);
  }

  let interval = setInterval(() => {
    if (document.head) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      interceptData();
    }
  }, 100);
}
inject_response_interceptor();
```

In the manifest dont forget to add the contentScript.js to be injected at documentStart:

**manifest.js**

```
...
"content_scripts": [{
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "*://*/*"],
      "run_at": "document_start",
      "js": ["contentScript.js"]
    }]
```