# Listen for "Refused to execute script... because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled." error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mime-types

I have a react app that intermittently on deploying looks to fetch a bundled JavaScript asset that does not exist yet on the server. The error surfaces itself with the error

```
Refused to execute script from 'https://example.com/mycookscript.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

Because it is requesting a non existing asset, and my server is returning with a 404 type=text/html page.

How would I listen for this specific error and do some action upon listening to it?

For example, the event listener code:

`window.addEventListener('error', function (e) { console.log(e) });`

Logs nothing when the error `refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:3000/foo' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.` is surfaced in the browser.

Comment: "*listen for this specific error and do some action*" - what action do you have in mind?

Comment: Why not just fix the error and a) don't request non-existing assets b) serve your 404 response with `application/javascript` mimetype (and an empty/comment-only content) for `.js` paths?

Comment: In `/*do something*/` you look at the error text and search for the text that distinguishes that specific error. Then you "do some action". There's no magic to be had here. This doesn't happen often enough to warrant a special error type or something.

Comment: Posed a different way, what is the best way to reproduce that error in an express/react app? Returning html from a route that is referenced via a script tag, like `<script src="/some-html-file"></script>`, returns `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' ` instead of the MIME type error

Comment: Update - `window.addEventListener('error', function () {console.log(e)});` does *not* log anything when this specific error is surfaced in the browser. Hence there is some "magic to be had" @HereticMonkey

Comment: Not really, it just means you have to catch the error differently. See [Is there a global approach to catch network errors in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19098450/215552)

Comment: @Afs35mm Put an `onerror` handler on the `<script>` element itself. Or use `import()` instead.